# Code analysis in F#

Tags: f#, code-analysis

As a C# developer I've benefited from Microsoft's Code Analysis. In F# however, Code Analysis doesn't seem to be an integrated part of the development cycle. It took me a while to enable CA on an F# project, but this [blog helped](http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2013/09/08/how-to-enable-code-analysis-for-fsharp-projects/). Now that I have CA enabled, it seems to produce "wrong" warnings. For instance, I have a declared a record type as

```
type Account = {Number : string}
```

for which I expect structural equality by default. [This blog](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/10/fsharp-referential-equality-for-tuples-discriminated-unions-and-records/) demonstrates that two instances of type Acccount, for which the number is the same, should be equal. Why does the code analysis then tell me that: 'Account' should define operator '!=' since it implements IComparable? For sure, had this been a C# class then I would have to jump through all those hoops, but in F# this should happen automagically.

I am applying the "Microsoft All Rules" ruleset. Do these not apply to F#, and if so, is there any ruleset that I should use?

Comment: Those rules are aimed at C#. They just assume you're using C# and give you warnings appropriate for that. Are you sure you really need those rules? In my experience with F# I found that the language itself guides me in the right direction, I don't need external tools for that.

Comment: If you look at the first blog post you referenced, you'll see that the `Targets` file explicitly checks the language before running code analysis. Don't you think there is a reason for that?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Sure I found it weird that I had to modify a 'system-wide' file in order to get CA, but some rules will hopefully still be relevant to an F# project. I'm also hoping someone reading this question will point me to an F# ruleset that I can download (if such a thing exists).

Comment: Out of curiosity what are you looking for code analysis to do for you? I am asking because what one person may expect from code analysis is not the same as what another may expect. I know the obvious answer is to find things that cause bugs, but in my view that requires the definition of bug to be objective and most definitions of bugs I see are more subjective than objective.

Comment: @GuyCoder Truthfully, I'm not sure what code analysis can do for me in the F# context. I just fixed one warning saying that a variable uri should not be of type string but System.Uri, so that's a valuable one. On the other hand, since I'm not really proficient in F#, I want some tool to yell at me when I do it wrong, and in C# the CA really does help me.

Comment: Like I said above, in F# the compiler itself is usually perfectly capable of yelling at you when you do something wrong. Just take care not to ignore warnings.

Comment: Here a bit of advise that I don't think you will see often but I personally use it all of the time; put the type signatures in when you first start a new function or project, and then after you have the code running without bugs, start to remove the type signatures so that the code becomes generic. This way the compiler will `yell at you more` than not because it will not be able to make something generic to get around a problem which you did not mean to introduce. Also avoid side effects and mutable if possible.

Comment: Another thing you can do, but I have done in years is to turn on [verbose syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/verbose-syntax-%5Bfsharp%5D) but it will be hard to get help from others as most people don't use it anymore, but it will `yell at you even more` and help you to understand how the code works with all of the added `in` keywords.

Comment: FSharpLint is integrated into F# Power Tools.

Comment: If you *really* need Code Analysis (FxCop) in F# projects, here's [a way to enable it in MSBuild](http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2013/09/08/how-to-enable-code-analysis-for-fsharp-projects/). This post is quite old, but can probably work even with newer versions of MSBuild...

Comment: My conclusion is to include Code Analysis as well as FSharpLint. @s952163 Please post your comment as answer such that I can 'close' this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [FSharpLint](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpLint/) in [Visual F# Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff/) :

[image]