# Code Analysis for F# in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, f#, code-analysis

In Visual Studio 2015, the F# Power Tools could be installed for F# code analysis, as pointed out in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37797304/code-analysis-in-f). I have not been able to find a tool for code analysis (even for just line count) for F# in Visual Studio 2017. Is there a package available for this, and furthermore is it known if Visual Studio 2019 will have code analysis for F#?